# opencart seo_url not working for categories

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");
echo "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'";
exit();
```

i have added the keyword for the category and the output for this echo is

```
SELECT * FROM oc_url_alias WHERE keyword = 'fashion'
```

i echoed this part in seo_url.php under controller/common.
this is working for products and information but not for category even when i run this output query in sql it gives me a single row with keyqord ='fashion'

how can the query be right, yet it gives 0 when keyword is for category.

Comment: Probably because product categories are managed in a different way, check your database structure.

Comment: in opencart there is a common table for both called url_alias.i executed the query echoed for both product and category and both gives the row they belong to.

Comment: Do you have anywhere else with the keyword 'fashion' such as info pages, products etc? Do a print_r on the result to see if there's more than one row

Comment: i executed the query in the database directly as well, give a single row with keyword 'fashion'

Comment: If you've not modified the database tables, the collation should be utf8_bin which IS content sensitive. Are you calling the keyword in the proper case?  Also can you show us the row data from the db that contains the keyword "fashion"?

Comment: well, i corrected it, it was a file running in vqmod making the changes in real time.thanx anywayz